# Store previous element of loop in intermediate variable for dynamic command creation

Tags: expansion, loops, etoolbox, csv

I am dynamically creating commands and would like to define them based on the current value in an iteration list. The problem is that the current value appears as the last value of the iterated variable.

Here's a MWE. This example is obviously meaningless, but an application I can think of is remembering the last value in the loop. I've tried many variations of `\expandafter`, `\edef`, and can't figure it out. I've been reading about expansion. I would like to define some intermediate variable and push it to the commands I generate so that it should display "1:1, 2:2".

[image]

```latex
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\begin{document}%
    \noindent%
    \newcounter{n}%
    \setcounter{n}{0}%
    \renewcommand{\do}[1]{%
        \let\Num#1%
        \setcounter{n}{#1}%
        \expandafter\newcommand\csname C\alph{n}\endcsname{\textbf{#1}: \Num}% create a command
    }%
    \docsvlist{1,2,3,4}%
\Ca\\
\Cb\\
\end{document}
```

**EDIT:**

Here is a more illustrative example. I would like to define a command that displays the current number, and previous number in the loop, but the previous number is always the last in the list.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xintexpr}
\begin{document}%
    \noindent%
    \newcounter{n}%
    \setcounter{n}{0}%
    \renewcommand{\do}[1]{%
        \edef\evenodd{\xintthe\xintiexpr\value{n}/:2\relax}% get the column num
        \ifnum\evenodd=0%
            \let\PrevNum#1%
        \fi
        \ifnum\evenodd=1%
            \expandafter\newcommand\csname C\alph{n}\endcsname{prev: \PrevNum, current: #1}% create a command
        \fi
        \setcounter{n}{#1}%
    }%
    \docsvlist{1,2,3,4,5,6}%
\Ca\\
\Cc\\
\Ce\\
\end{document}
```

Comment: What's wrong with `\textbf{#1}: #1`? Maybe you want to show a more meaningful example.

Comment: @egreg I'm deliberately avoiding that for conceptual purposes. My full working example is more complicated and I wanted to strip it down.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't understand what you mean by “previous element in a loop” and “remembering the last value in the loop”.

Comment: @egreg Thanks for trying--I've included a more illustrative example in an edit that will hopefully explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really clear what the final aim is. However, `\let` is not the right tool and you should use `\def`. Also, you need to access the expansion of `\PrevNum`, rather than the control sequence.

```latex
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xintexpr}

\newcounter{n}
%\setcounter{n}{0}%
\renewcommand{\do}[1]{%
  \edef\evenodd{\xintthe\xintiexpr\value{n}/:2\relax}% get the column num
  \ifnum\evenodd=0
    \def\PrevNum{#1}%
  \fi
  \ifnum\evenodd=1
    \definetablecommand{C\alph{n}}{#1}{\PrevNum}%
  \fi
\setcounter{n}{#1}%
}
\newcommand{\definetablecommand}[3]{%
  \expandafter\definetablecommandaux\expandafter{#3}{#1}{#2}%
}
\newcommand{\definetablecommandaux}[3]{%
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname #2\endcsname{prev: #1, current #3}%
}

\docsvlist{1,2,3,4,5,6}

\begin{document}

\Ca

\Cc

\Ce

\end{document}
```

Note that `%` after constants is wrong and could lead to unexpected results.

Doing such things inside `document` is also disputable.

[image]

With a different programming style.

```latex
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\definetablecommands}{m}
 {
  \ilikethevegetable_dtc_main:n { #1 }
 }

\seq_new:N \l__ilikethevegetables_dtc_data_seq
\tl_new:N \l__ilikethevegetables_dtc_item_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \ilikethevegetable_dtc_main:n
 {
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__ilikethevegetables_dtc_data_seq { #1 }
  \seq_map_indexed_inline:Nn \l__ilikethevegetables_dtc_data_seq
   {% ##1 is the current item index, ##2 is the current item
    \int_if_odd:nTF { ##1 }
     {% remember the item
      \tl_set:Nn \l__ilikethevegetables_dtc_item_tl { ##2 }
     }
     {% define the control sequence
      \cs_new:cpx { C \int_to_alph:n { ##1 - 1 } }
       {
        \exp_not:n { prev:~} \exp_not:V \l__ilikethevegetables_dtc_item_tl ,~
        \exp_not:n { current:~ ##2 }
       }
     }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\definetablecommands{1,2,3,4,5,6}

\begin{document}

\Ca

\Cc

\Ce

\end{document}
```